# Is it correct to use "at" while telling your age?

Tags: prepositions

Please check the sentences and let me know your valuable feedback (My one friend said this to me and he meant to say "he is 24 years old" so I told him that "at" is unnecessary here, but he did not agree with me, so I just wanted to confirm this).

I think **at** is completely unnecessary here:

> I am at 24 years old.

It should be:

> 1- I am 24.
>
> 2- I am 24 years old.

Comment: where did you read it? Give us some reference or is it *your made* sentence?

Comment: My one friend said this to me and he meant to say "he is 24 years old" so I told him that "at" is unnecessary, but he did not get agree with me, so I just want to confirm that.

Answer (score 6):

You are right; it is not necessary. However, it's not grammatically incorrect.

Most of the time, I wouldn't use *at* when expressing my age. However I can imagine myself in an occasional dialogue that goes something like this:

> *My knees seem to ache more and more all the time nowadays*.
>   Yes, it's rough getting old. Say, how old are you, anyway?
>   *Me? I'm at 44*.

In this context, the person is giving their age as though they are telling where they are in long race:

> I'm at Mile 13; I'm halfway done with my marathon.

It's not a common usage, but it's not an incorrect one, either. Still, you are correct to say that the word *at* is not needed. Most of the time, I'd recommend omitting it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for explaining the context. Yes, you are right. **In the given context,** *I'm **at** 24 years old* does not sound natural to me.

> I'm 24 years old.

OR

> I'm 24.

works.

Though, *at age* is also possible...

> You should feel the strength the way *I feel at 24.*

Comment: I am, at 24 years old, past my prime as a gymnast.

Comment: Yeah...though I'd prefer *At 24, I past my prime as a gymnast.*

Comment: That would have to be "At 24, I **passed** my prime..." and has a different nuance. In my structure, the point of primacy could have been anytime, e.g. at 17 years old. In your example, the peak was at age 24, after which it was all downhill...

Comment: Aw, I meant to say *passed* only. I read it incorrectly. @toandfro